# Is Shuffling of a regular language regular too?

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions, finite-state-machine

If $A$ be regular language, How we can prove that $A^{'}$ is regular too?

$A^{'} = \{a_{2}a_{1}a_{4}a_{3} ... a_{2n}a_{2n-1} \mid a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}...a_{2n} \in A\}$

Is there any way to prove that even/odd part of a regular language is regular?

$W = a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}...a_{2n} \in A$

$even(W) = a_{2}a_{4} ... a_{2n}$

$odd(W) = a_{1}a_{3}...a_{2n-1}$

**NOTE**: I know the shuffling of two regular language is regular. e.g. if $A$ and $B$ languages are regular then $C$ is regular too:

$A=\{w \mid w = a_{1} a_{2}...a_{k}\}$

$B=\{w \mid w = b_{1} b_{2}...b_{k}\}$

$C=\{w \mid w = a_{1}b_{1} a_{2}b_{2}...a_{k}b_{k}\}$

Comment: I haven’t thought about it too hard but it seems to me that it should be relatively straight-forward to construct a finite state machine that accepts the even (or odd) part of a regular language $L$ given a finite state machine for $L$.

Comment: You should be able to build that with epsilon transitions i think

Comment: like with two copies of the automaton for L, A1 and A2, but the transitions for A1 lead to A2, and all transitions from A2 are replaced with epsilon-transitions to A1

Comment: @Nephanth I tried that, in my deleted answer.  It's clear that the automata so constructed accept $odd(W)$ and $even(W)$, but I haven't been able to show that that's all they accept, and I suspect it's not true.

Comment: You have not ? Where does the problem happen ? Because from the feel of it, since the chain of transitions, is each time one transition A1 -> A2, then one A2 -> A1, and all of these correspond to a transition in the original automaton, you could build a word $a \in L$ with these transitions (and the accepted word is even(a))

Answer (score 2):

Let $L$ be a regular language on the alphabet $A$ and let $B = A^2$. For instance, if $A = \{a, b\}$, then $B = \{aa, ab, ba, bb\}$. Let $f, g: B^* \to A^*$ be the monoid homomorphisms defined by $f(a_1a_2) = a_1a_2$ and $g(a_1a_2) = a_2a_1$, respectively. I claim that
$$
L' = f\bigl(g^{-1}(L \cap (A^2)^*)\bigr)
$$
Since regular languages are closed under intersection, homomorphisms and inverse homomorphisms, this shows that $L'$is regular.

To prove the claim, take a word $u$ of $L \cap (A^2)^*$. Then $u$ is a word of even length, say $u = a_1a_2 \dotsm a_{2n-2}a_{2n}$. Now $g^{-1}(u) = [a_2a_1][a_4a_3] \dotsm [a_{2n}a_{2n-1}]$, where each $[a_{2i}a_{2i-1}]$ is a letter of $B$. Finally $f(g^{-1}(u)) = a_2a_1a_4a_3 \dotsm a_{2n}a_{2n-1}$.